# Keeping network architecture in mind, Why Redis Sentinel not a good architecture. But setting up external zookeeper is good for production Solr

Tags: networking, solr, redis, apache-zookeeper, network-protocols

I am confused with my little knowledge of Redis, Zookeeper, Solr. 
Help me in understanding network architecture of Redis Sentinel, zookeeper.

Both Redis Sentinel and Zookeeper at a high level look functionally similar. Choosing master and slaves and monitoring.

Redis cluster was introduced with different architecture where separate servers for monitoring not required. This also mentioned as cons of Sentinel.

Solr document says in production it is good to setup external zookeeper to maintain Solr.

Can someone explain me on the **network protocols/architecture level** like why one is good and the other one is not?

**--Updated**

My question is not specific to Redis Sentinel or Solr. Rather, it is on the architecture.

In Redis keeping sentinel outside was not really helping. It was creating unnecessary overhead as Sentinel also needs to be maintained in separate servers.
So they came up with Redis cluster where no external servers required for maintaining/choosing master/slave.

In case of Solr, though they have internal zookeeper, they suggest to keep external zookeeper in production Solr as best practice.

In above cases, for me it looks like both are architecturally opposite, which they say as best practice.

Please help me to understand at an architecture level, how it is helping in Solr and not in Redis usecase

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, so please expand your question in that case: I think the reasoning is on the side of network protocol level - Zookeeper is not a Solr project. It's a separate Apache project that fits what Solr needs. It is maintained separately from Solr. It's also useful that Zookeeper doesn't disappear if the Solr service goes down. There are also many situations where you'd want far more Solr nodes than Zookeeper nodes to keep intranode communication to a minimum.

Comment: Updated my question.